# Maven Cyclic reference when root pom has plugin which is common to two or more child modules

Tags: java, maven, plugins, pom.xml

So i have a project with the structure as follows-:

```
pom.xml
\
 ---Module A (Child)
 ---Module B (Maven child  plugin with Dependency on A)
 ---Module C (Child Dependency on A)
 ---Plugin B
```

the parent pom looks like the following

```
<modules>
<module>A</module>
<module>B</module>
<module>C</module>
</modules>

<plugins>
<plugin>
  B
</plugin>
</plugins>
```

POM for A has no dependencies and has just the parent-:
parent

POM for B has

```
<parent>parent</parent>
<dependencies>
      <dependency>A</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

POM for C also has

```
<parent>parent</parent>
<dependencies>
      <dependency>A</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

With the above,maven gives me the following error-:

org.apache.maven.ProjectCycleException: The projects in the reactor contain a cyclic reference:

Edge between 'B' and 'A' introduces to cycle in the graph A->parent->B->A

What am i doing wrong and how should i structure the project?I want to keep everything in one place.

Comment: You should never build a plugin in the same reactor where you will use it cause that means you build itself is dependent on a plugin which is under development which make not really sense...Better is to have the plugin in a separate project. May be you can give more details about that plugin and why you need to implement a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your plugin declaration inside of the parent into the `pluginManagement` tag so that you can set the version (but not actually use it), and then in individual projects that need the plugin, simply name the plugin in your `plugins` tag.

Additionally, `A` cannot use plugin `B` if `B` depends upon `A`. Sorry, can't be done; You'll need to find a way to make one do without the other. Additionally I don't think `B` can use itself as a plugin, since that has to resolve before it can even begin to build `B`. `C` and any other modules (`D`, `E`, etc.) can use `B` though.